# How do I add interface aliases using Network Manager GUI?

Tags: network-manager, adapter

I have seen numerous tutorials for creating network interface aliases (for assigning multiple IPv4 addresses to a single interface), but I seem unable to find one for using the Network Manager GUI.

Is it even possible? Or is Network Manager yet to support this feature?

Comment: What kind of virtual network adapter do you mean? tun/tap, emulated, bridge interface for virtual machines, etc.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Similar to one achieved in this tutorial http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/create-virtual-network-adapters-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Comment: Ah, well, that's rather odd terminology used there. You mean 'aliased interface' for using multiple IPv4 addresses on a single interface.

Answer (score 1):

In Network Manager, change the IPv4 settings for the network configuration from "Basic settings" to "Additional addresses" and add as many aliases as you like in the list. See the screenshot below.

[image]

*While the image is taken on KDE, the GUI should look similar on other desktop environments.*

For example, Ubuntu GNOME 14.04:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have one address obtained through DHCP and then several manually set? The current interface (14.10) forces me to do all manually.