# How do I add an additional IP address to an interface in Ubuntu 14

Tags: alias, ip-address

I want to have the wired interface simultaneously obtain a DHCP address, and also alias a fixed address so I can communicate with a device with a fixed IP address on a different subnet over the same link.

When searching for IP address aliasing in Ubuntu, I found this article [How do I add interface aliases using Network Manager GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442318/how-do-i-add-interface-aliases-using-network-manager-gui). Unfortunately, the Edit Connections GUI in Ubuntu 14 does not have the "additional addresses" button.

Where has this functionality moved?

Comment: I have updated that answer with another screenshot, see if it helps. But at any rate, I don't think the GUI allows you to have a DHCP and a static address at the same time - multiple static addresses are fine.

Comment: Correct - I tried setting it to manual, adding my static address and switching back to DHCP. Doing so deletes any manual addresses.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Skip the gui and do it via command line.

The following link provides detailed information on how to create the alias on a temporary basis, as well as how to edit the interfaces file to make the change permanent.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-or-adding-new-network-alias-to-a-network-card-nic/

Information from site in case of site death:

ifconfig command line

You can use ifconfig command to configure a network interface and alias. For example:

- eth0 NIC IP 192.168.1.5
- eth0:0 first NIC alias: 192.168.1.6

To setup eth0:0 alias type the following command as the root user:

```
# ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.6 up
```

Verify alias is up and running using following command:

```
# ifconfig -a

# ping 192.168.1.6
```

However, if you reboot the system you will lost all your alias. To make it permanent you need to add it network configuration file.

```
# vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Append the following to the file (This is in addition to existing information, not a replacement for it)

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
name Ethernet alias LAN card
address 192.168.1.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
network 192.168.1.0
```

Save and close the file. Restart the network:

```
# /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Thanks!  the "ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.6 up" command works great. I don't need it to persist, so that is a perfect solution.

Comment: Just note: `ip` utility is now recommended way to manupulate interfaces ( http://serverfault.com/a/458639/115256 ). Here's the HowTo: http://askubuntu.com/a/547297/53738

Comment: Why is there no `gateway` entry in the config above?

Comment: @Colin'tHart: you can only have one "default gateway" (there are special cases, but that is another story), so if the "main" network config already have a gateway, you should not put any in this alias. If the "main" network have no gateway, you can add in the alias the gateway, specially if it is related to this ip range

Answer (score 5):

In order to add an address temporarily use `ip`:

```
ip a add 192.168.178.2/24 dev enx0050b60c19af
```

For example to install OpenWRT on some old devices:

https://openwrt.org/toh/avm/avm_fritz_wlan_repeater_450e

Comment: How do you make that change _permanent_ (in 2022)?

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn Edit the correct configuration file for your system.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned a trick from my colleague which involve the following:

If say `eth_lan0` is set as the name of your wired network and has first been configured with the IP `192.168.1.2`, say with something like `netplan`, you can then add an alias to connect to another internal network say with an IP with the pattern `10.42.0.x` with the following:

```
sudo ifconfig eth_lan0:1 10.42.0.2
```

This assumes that the IP `10.42.0.2` has not yet been assigned to your LAN and that your host is connected to both networks, one with IP `192.168.1.x` and the other with `10.42.0.x`. Check if you have been successful by running `ifconfig` to see if the alias has been set. Then, it would be recommended to ping the hosts you are trying to connect on the two local networks to make sure everything runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below steps to add IP Address in a ubuntu network interface.

1. Login to Ubuntu server via ssh.
2. Hit the Following Command.

**`nano /etc/network/interfaces`**

3. Enter the interface alias **eth0:0** as mentioned in below.

(**Note**: If you already have interface alias eth0:0, you can add eth0:1 or eth0:2 for additional IP Address)

```
#secondary ip address
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 1*3.2*8.149.***
netmask 255.255.255.***
```

4. Below Command will up the added interface alias within the network.

`ifconfig eth0:0 1*3.2*8.149.*** up`

5. Restart the network service.

**`/etc/init.d/networking restart`**

6. check the newly added ip address with the below command.

**`ifconfig`**

It is Done.