# Multiple public IP's assignment on same server Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, networking, 18.04, 18.10, ip-address

Is it possible to assign multiple public IP's to a single ubuntu server? Below is my requirement and need your valuable inputs.

My application is a platform where my clients connect to and they have our IP whitelisted and communication is perfect so far. But my application connects to other servers from where my clients fetch the data/information and those servers needs a unique IP's from my side for each of my clients. Now i have a public IP which is already whitelisted at the server my application connects to for my clients but they strictly has policy  that every client should have a different unique IP to fetch the data from their server.

As of now, i have a requirement of 150 public IP to be allowed from my single server to the server i connect to. My server is based out of the cloud provider. How do i go about it? appreciate your support and suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I (from CLI) assign multiple IP addresses to one interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547289/how-can-i-from-cli-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-interface)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create something that is called alias interface. I'm not familiar with how to configure this on Ubuntu Server, as I used only Debian and RedHat/CentOS on servers, and Ubuntu only on desktop. However, there is some answer here that might be useful to you: [How do I add an additional IP address to an interface in Ubuntu 14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585468/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ip-address-to-an-interface-in-ubuntu-14)

Comment: alias interfaces do not work on new Netplan driven systems.  You'd have to do a much more chaotic configuratoin of multiple IP addresses on the system adn then 1:1 NAT matching for specific connection protocols (which may not be doable if this is a client side application)

Comment: Yet at least using Network Manager GUI it is possible to add additional IP addresses to an interface?

Comment: yes, with custom configuration of the network manager components.  That doesn't fix the outgoing traffic problem of "How do I tell the client to reach out over a specific IP on the system" but that's a different issue.  (Network Manager integrates with Netplan nowadays)

Comment: Thanks for the time. In this case, since my server resides at cloud, can i add multiole interfaces and the assign an IP to each once? will that be fine and will work?

Comment: This depends on if your cloud provider allows this.