# NetworkManager and /etc/network/interfaces defined virtual interface simultaneously

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I'm trying to add a virtual interface, and following is the current configuration:

```
$ less /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
        post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules

auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet manual
```

---

```
$ less /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

I've tried both `true` and `false` on `managed`, but `eth0:0` still doesn't show on `ifconfig`:

```
$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:4b:62:f8:f4  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:e4600000-e4620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:121285 (121.2 KB)  TX bytes:121285 (121.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:77:bc:16:d5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:77ff:febc:16d5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3048 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1593844 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:511234 (511.2 KB)
```

As you can see, I've a `wlan0` interface, as such I'd prefer if NM is still working besides my manual network configuration instead of straight-off removal.

Comment: Change in `/etc/network/interfaces` form `managed=false` to `managed=true`.

Comment: @2707974 I tried them both. I mentioned it in the question.

Comment: You need `eth0:0` with address from `dhcp` or you can setup statis ip?

Comment: @2707974 Is it necessary? I want to dedicate the virtual interface to connect the PC's virtual bridge to the physical bridge connected to `eth0`.

Comment: try with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you have one nic you can add virtual interfaces on this way

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.57
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   up ip addr add 192.168.0.57/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
   down ip addr del 192.168.0.57/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
```

I use `192.168.1.0/24` net range for `eth0` and `192.168.0.0/24` for `eht0:1`. Change based on your need.

You must edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

This will open the `NetworkManager.conf` file in our text editor.

Now change:

```
managed=false
```

to

```
managed=true
```

After changes reload network service

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Or if this did not work, try

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

Edit 1

tray to add only

```
iface eth0:0 inet dhcp
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: I'm going out now, I'll try it later. But is there no way to get `eth0:*` up without any IP?

Comment: You have mu edit 1.

Comment: You need to restart nm: `/etc/init.d/network-manager restart` and it should be `managed=false`...

Comment: @o9000, nope, `managed=true`. Check.

Comment: How about taking a different approach and letting NetworkManager handle both eth0 and etho:0? http://askubuntu.com/questions/442318/how-do-i-add-interface-aliases-using-network-manager-gui or http://askubuntu.com/a/496119/428973

Comment: `up ip addr` can apply to to bridges as well, right?